# Get the Thumb of a Slider

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm just trying to figure out a way to get the thumb of a slider in WPF, something like so:

```
Slider mySlider = new Slider();

Thumb thumb = slider.Thumb;
```

Now I know it's not possible as simple as this; but there must be a work around this. Let me know if you know any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Slider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=VS.85).aspx) has a [`TemplatePartAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx) that declares it should have a template part called `PART_Track` of type [`Track`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.track(v=VS.85).aspx).  The `Track` can give us a reference to the `Thumb`.  Keep in mind that it's possible to give the `Slider` a template with no `Track`, in which case there will be no `Thumb`.

```
private static Thumb GetThumb(Slider slider)
{
    var track = slider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", slider) as Track;
    return track == null ? null : track.Thumb;
}
```

Comment: in my case, slider.Template == null, what should I do now?

Comment: any solution when Template is null for the slider?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add an event handler to the thumb and don't want to wait or force rendering to avoid `slider.Template` being `null`, you can do something like this:

```
slider.AddHandler(Thumb.DragStartedEvent, new DragStartedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    // Handling code
}));
```

Comment: This works well in OnApplyTemplate of a custom control CONTAINING the slider. Everything else I've tried with mouse events applies to the entire custom control -- not just the slider. :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution on my own, with a little help from the `VisualTreeHelper`. Any optimization greatly appreciated:

```
private Thumb Thumb
{
    get
    {
        return GetThumb(this /* the slider */ ) as Thumb;;
    }
}

private DependencyObject GetThumb(DependencyObject root)
{
    if (root is Thumb)
        return root;

    DependencyObject thumb = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); i++)
    {
        thumb = GetThumb(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i));

        if (thumb is Thumb)
            return thumb;
    }

    return thumb;
}
```