# How to add the Handler of Thumb.DragCompleted for a slider Programmatically in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, slider

I know the way to add it in .xaml file, but I need the way to add it in C# file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You find how to get the `Thumb` programmatically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233000/get-the-thumb-of-a-slider).

Then just add the Handler to event:

```
sliderThumb.DragCompleted += myDragCompletedHandler;
```

Comment: Thanks! But now the 1st problem I meet is that the slider.Template is null and I don't konw why.

Comment: I init the slider programmatically, so should I do sth. to init slider.Template?

Comment: slider.Template is null till the slider is rendered on the screen. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080375/force-rendering-of-a-wpf-control-in-memory) how to force rendering in memory

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I could find without messing with the `Thumb` property:

```
slider.AddHandler(Thumb.DragCompletedEvent, new DragCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
    // Handling code
}));
```